# How to change next(previous)Sibling color in list using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I just need onclick function, which will change the color of each next (previous) element of the list. But I don't understand how to do it. Please, help.

HTML (need two last buttons).

```
<ul id="myUL"><li>First element</li><li>Second element</li></ul>
<form>
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="append(this.form)">
        <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" onclick="remove()">
        <input type="button" id="addStart" value="Add in beginning" onclick="addBeg(this.form)"> 
        <input type="text" id="myinput" name="input" size="30" /><br />
        <input type="button" id="selectFirst" value="Select first element" onclick="selectFirstEl()">
        <input type="button" id="selectLast" value="Select last element" onclick="selectLastEl()">
        <input type="button" id="selectNext" value="Select next element" onclick="selectNextEl(this.form)">
        <input type="button" id="selectPrevious" value="Select previos element" onclick="selectPrevEl(this.form)">
</form>
```

JavaScript (functions for every button)

```
function append(form) {
        if (form.input.value) {
            var newItem = document.createElement("li");
            newItem.innerHTML = form.input.value;
            document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem);
        }
    };

    function remove() {
    var list = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var item = list.lastChild;
    list.removeChild(item);
}
    function addBeg(form) { 
         if (form.input.value) {
            var newItem1 = document.createElement("li");
            newItem1.innerHTML = form.input.value;
            document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem1);
            var list1 = document.getElementById("myUL");
            list1.insertBefore(newItem1,list1.childNodes[0]);
        }
    };

    function selectLastEl() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
            var liLast = ul.lastChild;
         var   liFirst = ul.firstChild;
        liLast.style.color = "green";

        if (liFirst.style.color == "green") {
            liFirst.style.color = "black";
        };

        return false;
    };
    function selectFirstEl() {
        var ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        var liLast = ul.lastChild,
        liFirst = ul.firstChild;

        liFirst.style.color = "green";

        if (liLast.style.color == "green") {
            liLast.style.color = "black";
        };

        return false;
    };
```

Comment: We don't do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is finding a way to tell the `selectNextEl` function, which element is the currently selected one. One could do that through searching for an element with `element.style.color == "green"`, but this would just cost us time and code. We should instead always store a reference to the currently selected element in a variable. If no element is selected, the vairable will be null.

```
var selectedElement = null;     //Initialization of selectedElement
```

The `selectNextEl()` will then first check, if an element is selected as we can't determine the next element, if no is selected. Then we will reset it's color and select the next sibling of it, just to apply the green color to it:

```
function selectNextEl() {
    //if selectedElement is not equal null
    if(selectedElement) { 
        //reset it's color
        selectedElement.style.color = "black";
        //set it's next sibling as the new selectedElement
        selectedElement = selectedElement.nextElementSibling;
        //apply green to new selectedElement
        selectedElement.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

I believe, you can do `selectPrevEl()` on your own now ;). Remove the `this.form` from their function calls in `onlick` if you want.
We now have do modify the existing functions to update `selectedElement` correctly.
I will post the correct code here and point out some mistakes in your old code below.
**Corrected Functions:**

```
function append(form) {
    if (form.input.value) {
        var newItem = document.createElement("li");
        newItem.innerHTML = form.input.value;
        document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(newItem);
    }
};

function remove() {
    var list = document.getElementById("myUL");
    var item = list.lastChild;
    list.removeChild(item);
}

function addBeg(form) {
    if (form.input.value) {
        var newItem1 = document.createElement("li");
        newItem1.innerHTML = form.input.value;
        var list1 = document.getElementById("myUL");
        list1.insertBefore(newItem1, list1.firstElementChild); 
    }
};

function selectLastEl() {
    //if selectedElement is not equal to null
    if(selectedElement)         
        //reset it's color
        selectedElement.style.color = "black";

    //set new selectedElement
    selectedElement = document.getElementById("myUL").lastElementChild;  
    //apply green color to it
    selectedElement.style.color = "green";                        
};

function selectFirstEl() {
    //if selectedElement is not equal to null
    if(selectedElement)         
        //reset it's color
        selectedElement.style.color = "black";

    //set new selectedElement
    selectedElement = document.getElementById("myUL").firstElementChild;  
    //apply green color to it
    selectedElement.style.color = "green";  
};
```

**Mistakes and Things you should be aware of:**

**First** off, you were using `firstChild`, `lastChild` and `childNodes`. Those functions can also return a [textNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text). It's safer to use `firstElementChild`, `lastElementChild` and `children`, as they always return tags. In your scenario it won't be an issue, until you change

```
<ul id="myUL"><li>First element</li><li>Second element</li></ul>
```

to

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li>First element</li>
    <li>Second element</li>
</ul>
```

in which case, you would get text instead, if you use those commands mentioned first.

**Second**, you were inside `selectLastEl` and `selectFirstEl` originally only checking if the opposite element was selected by e.g.

```
    if (liFirst.style.color == "green") {
        liFirst.style.color = "black";
    };
```

However, after appending more elements, it could be any of those, not necessarily the first or last one. So you either would need to check all other elements or reference the selected one through a variable.

**Third**, 
in your original `addBeg()` function, you were first appending the child and later inserting it again. The `appendChild(newItem1)` had no effect at all.

**Fourth**, care about indentation! There are handy tools like *Beautify* in modern IDEs, which do it for you.

Comment: if you'd use `nextSibling`, you might get text nodes. You don't want those.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but what is the "el"? How to describe it?

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov No problem, it isn't stupid. You are quite new to programming, aren't you? It's an *argument*, an variable that gets passed into the function from the place, it is called from.  
The function needs to know, which element is calling it, so it can determine it's next and previous sibling. Therefore I am calling the function with a `this` inside the brackets. It references the calling element (the `<input/>` tag here). `this` is then written to `el` and can therfore be accessed from inside the function. Hope this helps. You can ask more any time.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that clarifies. But why do we use brackets after `el.nextElementSibling`? Google Chrome gives an error message `Uncaught TypeError: el.nextElementSibling is not a function`. And without these brackets nothing happens.

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov oh, sorry, you are right, these aren't functions.

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov does it work for you now?

Comment: No. Somehow it changes the color of the text on the button "Select last element".

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov oh, sorry, I didn't read your question carefully enough. What exactly do you want to color? It's not clear to me from your question. Are you trying to select the last element via `selectNextElement` if the first element was selected before, or what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at English, therefore it is not clear. I'm trying to change the color of the next element in the list via `selectNext`. With buttons `add` and `addStart` I add elements to this list. For example, when I pressed the button `selectFirst`, first element of this list becomes green. And when I preesed the button `selectNext`, the second element becomes green. And so on... And the same for the button `selectPrevious`. For example, if 4th element is green, when I press the button `selectPrevious`, the 3rd element should become green.

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov sorry, got that totally wrong. I'll adapt my code to it in a minute

Comment: @DmitryChernyshov  now it should do, what you want.

Comment: Everything work perfectly. I also added the ability to select previous element from the first element, and next element from the last. And your idea of variable `selectedElement` is very good. Thank you so much for your help!